# Tratamento de String - Aplicação javaFX

Tags: java, string, javafx

Estou com um problema estou lendo um arquivo e preciso retirar os acentos das string,porem, a função não esta funcionando na minha aplicação JavaFX.

Função:

```java
public static String remove(String str) {
    return Normalizer.normalize(str, Normalizer.Form.NFKD).replaceAll("[^\\p{ASCII}]", "");
}
```

Numa aplicação Java essa função funciona perfeitamente, só na minha aplicação JavaFX não funciona.Na minha aplicação ele está removendo a letra. por exemplo: eu passo a palavra "gestão" e ele me retorna gesto. Sendo que na aplicação Java ela funciona normalmente. Nas duas aplicações as chamadas da função estão idênticas.

@edit

Consegui resolver o problema, era a codificação do arquivo.
Agora ele ta funcionando perfeitamente. So alterei a linha que faz a leitura.

```
buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(caminho), Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1")));
```

Comment: Testei em uma aplicação JavaFX e funcionou. Tem como dar maiores detalhes ou um exemplo reproduzível? Tentou com `str.replaceAll("\\p{M}", "")`?

Comment: Testei e não funcionou na minha aplicação JavaFx na outra aplicação funcionou. O que estou fazendo é lendo um arquivo csv e jogando pra um vetor dando split. De la eu pego a string que esta numa posiçao do vetor e jogo pra uma variavel e coloco na minha string de sql.

Comment: @iMakaay Por favor, publique a solução como uma resposta.

Answer (score 0):

Problema resolvido

```
buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(caminho), Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1")));
```